# How to search each record in file properly using "fseek()"

Tags: c, file, structure, fseek

I am working in this program and I'm having difficulties in the part i have to find and overwrite one part of the data.
I stored the students in `ab mode`.When I print the data in file that are stored they look fine.But when i wanna use `fseek()` to find the data, something goes wrong.
In this case i wanna find one of the students by Id and replace their ID. The problem is that I can only replace and fund the first person data. Others result like they don't exist.

```
void change_id()
    {
        int long pos;
        int id_temp;
        int new_id;
        FILE *ftemp;
        ftemp=fopen(file_person,"rb+");
        if(ftemp==NULL)
        {
            printf("\nError in file!");
            return;
        }
      while(fread(&nr1[nr_person],sizeof(struct person),1,ftemp))
      {  
    
       printf("\nGive the person Id:");
           fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%d",&id_temp);
        rewind(ftemp);
        fseek(ftemp,sizeof(struct person)*(id_temp-1),SEEK_SET);
        if(id_temp==nr1[nr_person].id)
        {
            printf("\nGive the new ID:");
            scanf("%d",&new_id);
            nr1[nr_person].id=new_id;
            fwrite(&nr1[nr_person],sizeof(struct person),1,ftemp);
            break;
        }
        else {
            printf("Id doesnt exist!");
            return;
    }
```

Maybe I didn't store correctly the students.
Here is what I did:

```
struct person{ //This is the struct i have done
    int id;
    char name[20];
    int pass;
}nr1[50];
int nr_person; //I was trying to use this like a student count
void register_person()
{                  //I'm I using the number person wrong?
    FILE *f;
    f=fopen("person.txt","ab");
    if(f==NULL){
        printf("Error!");
        return ;
    }
    nr_person++;
    nr1[nr_person].id=read_data(file_person);
    printf("Generated Id is %d",nr1[nr_person].id);
    printf("\nName : ");
    scanf("%s",nr1[nr_person].name);
    nr1[nr_person].pass=generate_password(nr1[nr_person].id,nr1[nr_person].name);
    
    fwrite(&nr1[nr_person],sizeof(struct person),1,f);

     if(fwrite!=0){
        printf("\n\n Data saved");}
        else printf("\nData not saved!");
fclose(f);
}
```

I have been struggling with this part. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You forgot to initialize nr_person.  nr1[nr_person] could be anywhere

Comment: `nr1[nr_person].id=new_id;` changes the ID, but ID was the key of the record (i.e. determines its position in the file). So logically you can't write it back in its old position. Rethink what you are doing.

Comment: @sttark, it is a global so defaults to zero.

Comment: `printf("\nError in file!");` prints a non-informative error message to the wrong stream.  Try `perror(path)`

Comment: This program seems to do all the right things in the wrong order. You should start by writing down the steps you want the computer to do, on paper.

Comment: regarding error messages: They should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  When the error is from a C library function, should also output the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  In such case, call `perror()` with your error message.   When not from a C library function then call: `fprintf( stderr, "your error message\n" )`

Comment: what is this: `if(fwrite!=0){` expected to do?   Suggest:   `size_t unitsWritten = fwrite( &nr1[nr_person], sizeof(struct person), 1, f );  if( unitsWritten == 0 ) { perror( "fwrite failed" ); }`

Comment: always check the result of call to `fopen()`, `fwrite()`,  `fread()`, `fseek()`, `scanf()` etc

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) insert an appropriate space: inside parens, inside brackets, inside braces, after commas, after semicolons, around C operators.  2) separate code blocks: `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` via a single blank line.  3) separate functions via 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent)

Comment: generally, when you want to replace a record in a file,  First find the record (this is usually reading each record until the desired record is found.  Then modify that record (don't modify the key field)  Then `fseek()` backward the length of the record. the `fwrite()` the modified record.  Note: each record must be exactly the same length

Comment: At first i wanted to change the password but then i tried to change the ID (so changing the ID was just a test,because i thought if i can make it work for ID i can make it work for the password too). The program continued to find only the first record or in some cases found and others but kept appending them in the end. Do you think that the main problem in this case is the way i have stored the structs or the way i"m trying to use the 'fseek()' .Thanks for ,your answers!!

Comment: And @user3629249 i will change those parts. Thanks for suggestions.